# Can't Deploying SSIS package

Tags: variables, deployment, ssis

I have a couple of SSIS packages that are using Excel Connection Manager with variables for the path to the file that it will import in a Foreach loop to get all files in a directory. I am getting a couple of errors but I can still run the package from inside of Visual Studio.

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Validation error. Data Flow Task: Package: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.        Package.dtsx    0

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Validation error. Data Flow Task: SPackage: The result of the expression "@[User::FilePath] " on property "\Package.Connections[Excel Connection Manager].Properties[ConnectionString]" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.     Package.dtsx    0

---

So it appears that the variables are being replaced with the filepath and name but since it gives me these errors I can't deploy it to my SQL Server.

I have DelayValidation = True on all tasks and containers.

How do I either get rid of the error or force VS to deploy it anyway?

Thanks in advance for you help!
Joe

Edit:
[image]

[image]

[image: More Pix]

[image]

Comment: Try setting the property `DelayValidation` to True on the Excel Connection Manager and any Data Flow Tasks that reference the connection manager. Does that resolve the deployment error? Otherwise, you need to set a safe design time value for `@[User::FilePath]` - presume it's a blank string at the moment

Comment: I do not see one for the task that has the error. 

What is "safe design time value" It has a value and is evaluated correctly in expressions box.

I will edit the post and leave a screen shot.

Comment: Your screenshot is at the Data Flow Level. Upper left corner (not pictured) will be the Control Flow. Set the DelayValidation property there. It might also be visible in the current screen if you click in the background, I can't recall for certain

Comment: As for a safe value, I don't know what you're doing with your Connection Manager and how @[User::FilePath] factors in to influencing it. Based on the supplied error messages, it would appear there is some interplay between the two

Comment: Everything in the second pic has the delayvalidation set to True.

Comment: I assume that the Foreach Loop for 47Plus xlsm sets the value of @[User::FilePath] per iteration? If so, ensure the design time value points to a valid xlsm file. e.g. `C:\ssisdata\47Plus\File1.xlsm` My assumption is that will clear up the design time validation error allowing you to deploy

Comment: The file is there but when I try to open it in Excel it says it is locked, could that be the reason? The errors only appear after I open the "Excel Connection Manager". So I copied the file path in that manager and pasted in the "run" dialog in windows and get that it is locked and it will be in "read-only" mode.

Comment: Possibly. A quick way to test would be to copy the file to a new location. Copy should be allowed even if the file is locked so something as simple as creating a folder called Processing; copy the file into that folder; and then point the variable to that file. If that takes care of the build and deploy issue, then you know the next error you will run into is someone opening your source files in exclusive mode.

Comment: That did not change anything.

Comment: I created a new Excel Connection Manager and deleted the old one. The deployment worked!